# Subquery returned more than one value

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Temp_expo') is not null
begin 
    drop table Temp_expo
end

set @query3 =  'SELECT SPCT_ID_REL_LOW,SPCT_ID_REL_HIGH,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by PDBC_PFX) as TempId  

INTO Temp_expo  
FROM ['+ @FCTServer +'].['+@FCTDBName+'].dbo.CMC_SPCT_SUPP_CONV  
where  SPCT_ID_REL_LOW <> '''' and SPCT_ID_REL_HIGH <> '''''

exec (@query3)

Select @minCount= min(TempId) from Temp_expo   
Select @maxCount= max(TempId) from Temp_expo  

create table #ICD9SPCT
(
    ICD9Code varchar(200)
} 

while @minCount<=@maxCount 
begin
    select @low=SPCT_ID_REL_LOW,@high=SPCT_ID_REL_HIGH 
    from Temp_expo 
    where TempId=@minCount 
    group by SPCT_ID_REL_LOW,SPCT_ID_REL_HIGH

    set  @loworder = (select ISNULL(OrderId,0) from FCT_ICD9_Diag_ORDER where ICD9=@low)
    set  @highorder = (select ISNULL(OrderId,0) from FCT_ICD9_Diag_ORDER where ICD9=@high)


    insert into #ICD9SPCT 
    select ICD9 from FCT_ICD9_Diag_ORDER ordert
    left join #ICD9SPCT icdorder on ordert.ICD9 = icdorder.ICD9Code
    where OrderId between @loworder and @highorder and icdorder.ICD9Code is null

    set @minCount = @minCount+1;
end
```

Above is the code in which i am getting this error .I found that error is due to below code plz help

```
set  @loworder = (select ISNULL(OrderId,0) from FCT_ICD9_Diag_ORDER where ICD9=@low)
set  @highorder = (select ISNULL(OrderId,0) from FCT_ICD9_Diag_ORDER where ICD9=@high)
```

Comment: Please include you table definition so I can point out where is wrong

Comment: which table's definition u want  CMC_SPCT_SUPP_CONV  
or FCT_ICD9_Diag_ORDER

Comment: This table contains 2 coloumns: OrderId and ICD9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set  @loworder = (select ISNULL(OrderId,0) from FCT_ICD9_Diag_ORDER where ICD9=@low)
set  @highorder = (select ISNULL(OrderId,0) from FCT_ICD9_Diag_ORDER where ICD9=@high)
```

You could either rewrite it as

```
select @loworder = ISNULL(OrderId,0) from FCT_ICD9_Diag_ORDER where ICD9=@low
select @highorder = ISNULL(OrderId,0) from FCT_ICD9_Diag_ORDER where ICD9=@high
```

if you're sure enough that there will be only one value as per criteria and you need only one value. If there are more than one records and you need them all then

```
SET  @loworder = STUFF(
       (select DISTINCT ';' + CAST(OrderId AS varchar(20))
       FROM FCT_ICD9_Diag_ORDER where ICD9=@low FOR XML PATH ('')
       ),1,1, '')
```

@loworder should be varchar(max)

I hope it helps!

Comment: i m facing timeout error know with present code, can u help me in optimizing it.This table CMC_SPCT_SUPP_CONV contains 2 millon records